# Get Post Value in Django

Tags: html, django, django-views

I would like to achieve getting a value from a post.
I have the following in my views.py:

```
def foo(request):
    number = request.POST.get('number')
    print(number)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
 <form action="{% url 'ms_app:foo' %}" method="POST">
    {% for i in model %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="number" value="{{ i.number }}">RESTART</button>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

URL Patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user_login/',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    path('registration/',views.registration,name='registration'),
    path('customers/',views.CustomerList.as_view(), name='customer_list'),
    path('customers/<pk>',views.SitDetail.as_view(), name='site_detail'),
    path('foo/',views.foo,name='foo'),
    ]
```

The output is none:

```
[05/Aug/2021 12:14:23] "GET /ms_app/customers/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 11714
None
[05/Aug/2021 12:14:24] "GET /ms_app/esp_rsrt/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[05/Aug/2021 12:14:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2650
```

I feel like this is a simple thing that I am doing wrong. I am very new to Django and new to asking questions here, so if I have done something wrong, please let me know so I can correct it.

Comment: You can not add a `method="POST"` attribute, etc. to an `<a>` tag.

Comment: It looks like you are making a request to `ms_app/esp_rsrt/`, not to the `foo/`.

Comment: There is something weird here, based on the logging, you submit it to `/ms_app/esp_rsrt/`, not `foo/`. Furthermore it is a GET request, not a POST request. Are you sure you updated the right template (with the buttons)?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use an `<a>`-tag to make a POST request, or at least not without JavaScript that handles submitting the form as a POST request.

What you can do is make a mini-form, and use buttons to submit data, so we can implement this as:

```
<form action="{% url 'ms_app:foo' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for i in model %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="number" value="{{ i.number }}">RESTART</button>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: Ok i also had a typo in my code. I now am able to get the number into my views.py file. Thank you, you were very helpful

Comment: Yes it is working